# Indexing a Vue dictionary with Laravel variable

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I would like to use Laravel's double curly bracket syntax inside of Vue's double curly bracket escaped with @ syntax.

In code below (which is not working), `savingNotes` is a dictionary in Vue, and I would like to use Laravel variable as a key to select an item for this dictionary.

```
@foreach($notes as $key => $note)
    <div class="note">
        <div class="note-heading">
            @{{ savingNotes[{{ $key }}] }}
            {{ $note->name }}
        </div>
        <hr class="note-hr">
        <div class="note-content">
            {{ $note->content }}
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [@verbatim directive](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-at-verbatim-directive) to escape parts that you would have transcluded by VueJS

```php
@verbatim {{savingNotes @endverbatim ['{{$key}}'] @verbatim }} @endverbatim
```

However this is code that is a head scratcher. A clearer approach would be to create a custom directive in VueJS and pass the keys to it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  directives: {
    'saving-notes': {
        inserted: function (el, binding, vnode) {
            el.innerHTML = vnode.context.savingNotes[binding.expression]
        }
    }
  },
  data: {
      savingNotes: {
        'test-key': 'testvalue'
      }
  },
})
```

Then in your blade template, write:

```html
    <div class="note-heading">
            <span saving-notes="{{$key}}"></span>
            {{ $note->name }}
    </div>
```